# GIT allowing merging of an outdated branch

Tags: git, merge

GIT is allowing a branch to be merged into central repo even though that branch is out-dated ( Other people has commit the changes to master which was not updated to the branch that was merged )

1. Developer A created a new branch "BugFix_A" on central repo. On his local machine, he did

   - A git pull to get the details of newly created branch.
   - git checkout BugFix_A
   - Perform the changes to 'FileA.txt", commit the changes to local branch

Meanwhile, another developer B merged new commits to the central master branch through his branch "BugFix_B"

Which means developer A branch "BugFix_A" doesnt yet have these new commits on his local copy of branch "BugFix_A". Developer A ( Not realizing that new commits are made in central repo master ) perform a "git push origin BugFix_A

My understanding is that git must reject this push as there are conflicts ( His branch BugFix_A does hold new commits but surprisingly the push was successfully.

Second problem is git also allows the branch BugFix_A to be merged into master on central repo overwriting the commits performed by developer B

Are there any issues with this workflow. I am sure I am doing something wrong.

[graphical representation of master branch being overwritten by outdated branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLVon.jpg)

Comment: Merges don't overwrite, but pushes also don't merge. If a push cannot be done cleanly without requiring a merge, it will fail unless you use `--force`, so just don't use `--force` without knowing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: thats exactly my point is. I am using this command "git push origin BugFix_A" without --force but git is still accepting the push and not throwing any error.

Answer (score 0):

`git push` created a new branch on origin called "origin/BugFix_A". The merge on master update the file "FileA.txt" with your changes done in "BugFix_A". As long as these changes are not affecting the lines of "BugFix_B" your changes are applied to the corresponding lines of master.

In case "BugFix_A" affects lines which ere changed by "BugFix_B" then a merge conflict will occur and you Need to fix them by merging master in "BugFix_A", resolve there and then try again to merge to master.